# android listview contains checkbox setonItemclick not working

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

when i click `listview` item which contains `textview` and checkbox, `setOnItemClickListener` not working

this is my java code

android `listview` contains checkbox `setonItemclick` not working

```
 etiket_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                final Database dbD = new Database(context); // Db bağlantısı oluşturuyoruz. İlk seferde database oluşturulur.
                Tags = dbD.Etiketler();
                final int  temp_id = Integer.valueOf(Tags.get(db.Etiketler().size()-position-1).get("tag_id"));
                final int pozisyon=db.Etiketler().size()-position-1;
                if (syac % 2 == 0) {
                    val_tag=val_tag+Tags.get(pozisyon).get("tag")+" ";
                    tag.setText(val_tag);
                    syac++;
                } else {
                    String newTags = tag.getText().toString().replaceAll(Tags.get(pozisyon).get("tag"),"");
                    syac++;
                    tag.setText(newTags);
                }

            }
        });
```

Here is my list item XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:background="#f8f8f8"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:id="@+id/item_li_frame">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="list_item_etiket2"
            android:id="@+id/list_item_etiket2"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:textColor="#4a4a4a"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etiket_checkBox"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Android `listview` contains checkbox `setonItemclick` not working

Answer (score 0):

You have placed a `TextView` and `CheckBox` in a `FrameLayout` so the `checkBox` lies above the `textView` and consumes the touch events. Place them in a different layout such as `LinearLayout`